# How to make a multivariate scatterplot by group mean?

Tags: r, plot

I am working with the European Social Survey data (round 10) and I wish to make a scatterplot between two variables, grouped by country mean. Basically make a plot like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovjvV.png)

My X-variable is "religiosity" and y-variable is "lgbt support".  I suppose that I must first calculate the means of the countries on both variables. For now, I have used the following command to calculate.

aggregate(ess$lgbtsupport, list(ess$cntry), FUN=mean,na.rm=T)

aggregate(ess$religiosity, list(ess$cntry), FUN=mean,na.rm=T)

How can I save it into the dataset and make a scatterplot, grouped by country means? I am not allowed for the project that I am working on to use tidyverse or dplyr.

Hope my questions makes sense. Thank  you very much!

Comment: Please provide data using `dput()`. Project = University assignment?

Comment: Hi Pax, thanks for your comment. I am not sure how to use the dput(). To say the least, it gave me a way too long code to ever copy. However, regard that I have the three following variables in my data set: 1) country (chr), 2) religiosity (int; 0-10-scale) and LGBT-support (int; 0-5-scale). In total, around 30.000 respondents. Those are the ones that I intend to use. Does that make sense? Again, thank you. I am trying my best to learn this awesome program :-) Best wishes, Jacob